# Gnome crashes - dbus-broker-launch: Too many open files

Tags: gnome, crash, d-bus, pop-os

I have been having an issue where GNOME just randomly crashes - I get a blinking cursor for a minute or two and then it automatically restarts. Of course the session is not preserved.
This happens at random times, sometimes twice a day, while doing random things.
Running Pop OS 22.04, kernel 6.4.6, Gnome v42.9, X11

It looks like there is something dispatching too many messages to the dbus, however I don't know how to debug that. There are two programs that have been running every time and that is Chrome and PHPStorm. The `dbus-monitor` doesn't reveal anything suspicious.

This is what I tried so far: memtest (no errors), increase number of open files to 32k, increased swap to 32GB.

Could anyone help me debug this, please?

Here is the log at the time of crash. The crash occured at 02:24:39, I included few lines prior to this which are always present before a crash.

```
Aug 13 00:54:06 pop-os systemd[1]: fwupd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 13 00:54:07 pop-os systemd-resolved[748]: Grace period over, resuming full feature set (UDP+EDNS0) for DNS server fd4e:92d9:517b:1:8f7f:940d:67ba:9048.
Aug 13 01:09:07 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 13 01:09:07 pop-os systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 13 01:09:07 pop-os systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
Aug 13 01:17:01 pop-os CRON[639844]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 13 01:39:08 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 13 01:39:08 pop-os systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 13 01:39:08 pop-os systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
Aug 13 02:09:01 pop-os CRON[646799]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Aug 13 02:09:08 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 13 02:09:08 pop-os systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 13 02:09:08 pop-os systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
Aug 13 02:17:01 pop-os CRON[647997]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os dbus-broker-launch[546557]: ERROR listener_dispatch @ ../src/bus/listener.c +42: Too many open files
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os dbus-broker-launch[546557]:       dispatch_context_dispatch @ ../src/util/dispatch.c +344
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os dbus-broker-launch[546557]:       broker_run @ ../src/broker/broker.c +219
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os gvfsd[546559]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os gnome-shell-calendar-server[546790]: gnome-shell-calendar-server[546790]: Lost (or failed to acquire) the name org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer - exiting
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os kernel: [143222.176502] rfkill: input handler enabled
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os kernel: [143222.177669] traps: ThreadPoolSingl[585720] trap int3 ip:560f2282fca5 sp:7fabfadf8750 error:0 in 1password[560f1f108000+7877000]
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os kernel: [143222.181964] Core Thread[557310]: segfault at 7f09b47d7423 ip 0000000000b63332 sp 00007f0e537fc3b0 error 4 in spotify[acb000+131a000] likely on CPU 0 (core 0, socket 0)
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os kernel: [143222.181981] Code: 8b 7f 08 4c 8d 4f 28 48 8b 57 28 4c 89 ce 48 85 d2 74 2b 49 8b 40 10 4c 89 ce 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 40 00 31 c9 <48> 39 42 20 0f 9c c1 48 0f 4d f2 48 8b 14 ca 48 85 d2 75 ea 4c 39
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os gnome-session[546745]: gnome-session-binary[546745]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os gnome-session-binary[546745]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os gvfsd[546893]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os slack.desktop[547174]: [35 preload-host-spawn-strategy] Dropping 0xcdc002483c0 (3) because of connection closed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os slack.desktop[547174]: (slack:2): Gkr-WARNING **: 02:24:39.009: dbus connection disconnected for unknown reason
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os org.remmina.Remmina.desktop[588545]: Terminated
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os sh[546941]: Terminated
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os google-chrome.desktop[548762]: [548756:548781:0813/022439.014808:FATAL:bus.cc(1226)] D-Bus connection was disconnected. Aborting.
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os google-chrome.desktop[548762]: [548756:548783:0813/022439.021752:FATAL:bus.cc(1226)] D-Bus connection was disconnected. Aborting.
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os google-chrome.desktop[548762]: [0813/022439.039992:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os google-chrome.desktop[548762]: [0813/022439.057076:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir /home/intossh/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/attachments/d32f8752-b388-4613-a5db-8359729afbbd: No such file or directory (2)
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os com.getpostman.Postman.desktop[566737]: [31 preload-host-spawn-strategy] Dropping 0x20380026c3c0 (3) because of connection closed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os com.getpostman.Postman.desktop[566737]: [3 preload-host-spawn-strategy] Dropping 0x1250730 (3) because of connection closed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os com.getpostman.Postman.desktop[566737]: [10 preload-host-spawn-strategy] Dropping 0x1da8002bc780 (3) because of connection closed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os gsd-media-keys[624498]: []
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os dbus-broker-launch[546557]:       run @ ../src/broker/main.c +261
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os dbus-broker-launch[546557]:       main @ ../src/broker/main.c +295
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os tracker-miner-fs-3[546587]: OK
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os dbus-broker[546726]: Dispatched 10662 messages @ 1(±2)μs / message.
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os 1password.desktop[585708]: [585708:0813/022439.009774:FATAL:bus.cc(1226)] D-Bus connection was disconnected. Aborting.
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os com.getpostman.Postman.desktop[566736]: 1691886279012 main info "Quitting app"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os dbus-broker-launch[546555]: ERROR launcher_run @ ../src/launch/launcher.c +1461: Return code 1
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os dbus-broker-launch[546555]:       run @ ../src/launch/main.c +152
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os dbus-broker-launch[546555]:       main @ ../src/launch/main.c +178
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os dbus-broker-launch[546555]: Exiting due to fatal error: -131
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os systemd[1]: run-user-1000-gvfs.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os [546989]: unity_inspector_on_unity_vanished: assertion 'conn != NULL' failed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os systemd[1]: run-user-1000-doc.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os systemd[546533]: xdg-permission-store.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os systemd[546533]: xdg-permission-store.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os gnome-shell[546765]: Lost or failed to acquire name org.gnome.Mutter.ScreenCast
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os gnome-shell[546765]: Lost or failed to acquire name org.gnome.Mutter.RemoteDesktop
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os nautilus[552710]: unity_inspector_on_unity_vanished: assertion 'conn != NULL' failed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os dbus-broker[546557]: Dispatched 85908 messages @ 9(±29)μs / message.
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os dbus-broker-launch[546555]: Caught SIGCHLD of broker.
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os systemd[546533]: dbus-broker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os systemd[546533]: dbus-broker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os systemd[546533]: dbus-broker.service: Consumed 3.035s CPU time.
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os google-chrome.desktop[548762]: X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (**) Option "fd" "26"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) event3  - Logitech G502 HERO Gaming Mouse: device removed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (**) Option "fd" "44"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) event9  - Asus WMI hotkeys: device removed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (**) Option "fd" "45"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (**) Option "fd" "69"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (**) Option "fd" "69"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) event4  - Logitech G502 HERO Gaming Mouse Keyboard: device removed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (**) Option "fd" "24"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (**) Option "fd" "47"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) event6  - Logitech Gaming Keyboard G910 Keyboard: device removed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (**) Option "fd" "48"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) event5  - Logitech Gaming Keyboard G910: device removed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (**) Option "fd" "49"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) event10 - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: device removed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (**) Option "fd" "50"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) event7  - Logitech PRO X Consumer Control: device removed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (**) Option "fd" "51"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) event8  - Logitech PRO X: device removed
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:72
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:71
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:74
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:69
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:70
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:64
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:65
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) systemd-logind: not releasing fd for 13:68, still in use
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:66
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:73
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os acpid: client 547037[1000:1000] has disconnected
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Deleting GPU-0
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os gnome-session-f[649123]: Cannot open display: 
Aug 13 02:24:39 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[546634]: (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```